# Selecting 5 Most Recent Records Of Each Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

The below statement retrieves the top 2 records within each group in SQL Server.  It works correctly, however as you can see it doesn't scale at all.  I mean that if I wanted to retrieve the top 5 or 10 records instead of just 2, you can see how this query statement would grow very quickly.

How can I convert this query into something that returns the same records, but that I can quickly change it to return the top 5 or 10 records within each group instead, rather than just 2?  (i.e. I want to just tell it to return the top 5 within each group, rather than having 5 unions as the below format would require)

Thanks!

```
WITH tSub 
     as (SELECT CustomerID, 
                TransactionTypeID, 
                Max(EventDate)     as EventDate, 
                Max(TransactionID) as TransactionID 
         FROM   Transactions 
         WHERE  ParentTransactionID is NULL 
         Group  By CustomerID, 
                   TransactionTypeID) 

SELECT * 
from   tSub 
UNION 
SELECT t.CustomerID, 
       t.TransactionTypeID, 
       Max(t.EventDate)     as EventDate, 
       Max(t.TransactionID) as TransactionID 
FROM   Transactions t 
WHERE  t.TransactionID NOT IN (SELECT tSub.TransactionID 
                               FROM   tSub) 
       and ParentTransactionID is NULL 
Group  By CustomerID, 
          TransactionTypeID
```

Comment: YOu should look at keyword Rank

Comment: Take a look at the windowing functions (OVER (PARTITION BY <group_col> ORDER BY <order_col>)

Comment: Thanks guys!  They did help and along with @Learning 's answer below, I was able to finalize it.  Works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Partition by to solve this type problem

```
select values from
(select values ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by <GroupColumn> order by <OrderColumn>) 
as rownum from YourTable) ut where ut.rownum<=5
```

This will partitioned the result on the column you wanted order by **EventDate Column** then then select those entry having `rownum<=5`. Now you can change this value `5` to get the top `n` recent entry of each group.

Comment: Perfect!  When MarkMonforti and @Evgeni mentioned Rank and Over as comments in my original question, I had implemented it, but wasn't sure how I could put Rank in as part of the where clause.  Your answer cleared that up.  Thanks!